# Endless BufferReader reading

Tags: java

I wrote some program that has to receive and send messages. But I have some troubles with streams. I start my server and program. Then I'm trying send message, but my program just freezes. I used telnet and it works. I use sockets in this project and try do some messenger.

```java
        out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        button.addActionListener(e ->{
            try {
                out.write(textField.getText() + "\n");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
            try {
                textArea.append(in.readLine()+"\n");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
            textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getText().length());
            textField.setText("");
        });
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new Main().Draw();
    }
}
```

```java
public class Server {
    private static ArrayList<Receiver> receivers = new ArrayList<>();

    public static ArrayList<Receiver> sockets(){
        return receivers;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try(ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4040)){
            while (true){
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                receivers.add(new Receiver(socket));
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

```java
@Override
public void run() {
    String message = null;
    while (true){
        try {
            message = in.readLine() + "\n";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        for(Receiver socket : Server.sockets()) {
            try {
                socket.out.write("Your message: " + message+"\n");
                socket.out.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. The current code you showed is incomplete.

Comment: Lack of any visible threading looks suspicious.

Comment: your problem might be caused by lack of flushing, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24312147/bufferedwriter-printwriter-outputstreamwriter-dont-flush-buffer-until-close

Comment: You are ignoring end of stream here: `in.readLine()`. It will return null at end of stream, at which point you should close the socket and stop reading.

Comment: You will be blocking the EDT. Almost *never* can you expect a GUI to work with network IO without multithreading. Look at the excellently-documented [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)